# Trying to import excel file(multiple sheets) into DB but getting only the last sheet data

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm trying to read(import) multiple sheets into my DB but the problem is that my code is reading all the files but writing the record of only last sheet from my file:

#importing dataset from file:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('sample501.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
print (dfs.keys()) #print the name of sheets
d = {k: v[['SR_NO', 'NTN', 'NAME']].values.tolist()
        for k, v in  pd.read_excel('sample501.xlsx', sheet_name=None).items()}

for k, v in dfs.items():
    columns = ['SR_NO', 'NTN', 'NAME']
    df_data = v[columns]
    records = df_data.values.tolist()
    d[k] = records

#for test sheetnames
print (d.keys())
```

The output is:
dict_keys(['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3', 'Sheet4'])
dict_keys(['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3', 'Sheet4'])
Task is complete.

So as it seems, its getting all sheets data but writing the record of only sheet 4 into my database

Comment: The variable in the first line is `fs`, but the second line prints `dfs`. What is `dfs`?

Comment: Where is the code of your database update operation? Your code looks right

Comment: Actually it is dfs in the first line also

Comment: Code For database:
sql_insert = '''
    INSERT INTO eg205
    VALUES (?,?,?)
'''
try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(sql_insert, records)
    cursor.commit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `concat` your records from all of your sheets:

```
cols = ['SR_NO', 'NTN', 'NAME']
dfs = pd.read_excel('sample501.xlsx', usecols=cols, sheet_name=None)
records = pd.concat(df for df in dfs.values()).to_numpy().tolist()
```